# Can a jenkins agent be configured by multiple controller instances?

Tags: jenkins, build, release, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to have a slave that is hooked up to two masters.  However, when I run the Jenkins JNLP I keep getting socket errors.  Has anyone had experience with this and been able to work around it?

```
    C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>java -jar "C:\Documents and Settings\Adm
inistrator\Desktop\test2-slave.jar" -jnlpUrl http://test2.site.com:8080/com
puter/Slave1/slave-agent.jnlp -secret b4161b716c31a8985d8eb2760fdc6a404693bbf86c
7262973554877759ea1db1
Dec 25, 2013 10:50:16 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Dec 25, 2013 10:50:16 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://test2.site.com:8080/]
Dec 25, 2013 10:50:16 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to test2.site.com:7777
Dec 25, 2013 10:50:47 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to test2.site.com:7777 (retrying:2)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:333)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:222)
```

I know that I can connect to the jenkins box on port 8080.  (I checked).

Comment: You can run more that one slave process. Just make sure each uses a different directory on the slave.

Comment: Yes, i did that, but still was unable to make it connect up:(

Comment: Did you follow this process on the [1]? Also, what OS are you running on?


1 -https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-RunningMultipleSlavesontheSameMachine

Comment: I think you're going to have to supply more details on what sort of "socket errors" you're getting. Have you ever got a slave running? Start with one and work from there :-)

Comment: Mark, I've added the stack trace in the original post.  Thanks

Comment: Did making masters run on different ports helped?

Answer (score 3):

you need to have two separate jar files and secret keys for two different masters.
I am seeing only one in the question.
Once you have got you can run them one after other so that same slave makes connection to two different masters.
Also it is important to note that you need Java version > 7.